# Flexbox issue across browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am experiencing an issue with flexbox layout which only manifests in IE11 (go figure!). Both Firefox and Chrome render the layout fine.

See for yourself
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbEoKb

Page title and Subtitle are horizontally centered in IE11, which means align-items:baseline is kicking in which it shouldn't because it's intended for vertical centering/baselining.

Which rendering is correct, IE's or the other one?

Did I miss something in my CSS?

P.S. For some reason, SO wants me to paste code from codepen.io, so I'm only pasting the markup here

```
<header class="site-headers flex-block flex-justified flex-fixed">
    <aside class="titles flex-block">
        <h1>Page title</h1>
        <h4>Subtitle</h4>
    </aside>
    <aside class="additional flex-block">
  <h3>Additional</h3>
    </aside>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't have access to IE 11, but looking at your code it doesn't seem like all the flexbox properties are prefixed for `-ms`. Could that be it?

Comment: no, that's not it, the ones that need to be prefixed, are